# Architectures of LLMs

Tags: llm, transformers

What does the architecture of a LLM look like? Which part stores the enormous parameters? I know the transformer model, but I don’t know how to scale it sensibly as LLMs do.

Answer (score 0):

I found this GPT-2’s architecture. It’s a linear list of 12 transformer decoders!

[image: GPT-2 Architecture]

Switch Transformers contain trillions of parameters, which mostly reside in FFN layers.

[image: Switch Transformers]